# How can I make this nested footer sticky to the bottom?

Tags: css, sticky-footer, border, html

I've been trying a few different things and I'm not sure how to make this footer stick to the bottom. The difficulty comes because there are a number of nested divs inside one another.
What I want to achieve is have the border-right and border-left wrappers go to the bottom of the page to surround the footer, but the footer should be at the bottom of the page.

to explain a bit all the nested divs: the body has the main tiling background image applied to it and #background has a transparent overlay that makes it fade out toward the edges.
the border-right and border-left divs have a repeating image as background that serves as borders to the content div.

And the footer div should be totally separate I know, but when I make it so it stays centered to the width of the window rather than the width of the border-left so it looks wonky when the screen gets shrunk down.

Basic page structure is as follows and I have also posted a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cutcopypaste/zry4T/

```
<body>
<div id="background">
    <div id="container">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo"></div>
            <div id="menu">
                <p>Menu</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="border-left">
            <div id="border-right">

                <div id="content">

                    <p>Page Content</p>     
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Footer</p>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: you should [read this](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

Comment: @zzzzBov I've tried the technique outlined there and it does not work on my page: http://jsfiddle.net/cutcopypaste/zry4T/9/

Answer (score 0):

My solution:  http://jsfiddle.net/zry4T/15/

```
<body>
<div id="background">
    <div id="container">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo"></div>
            <div id="menu">
                <p>Menu</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="border-left">
            <div id="border-right">

                <div id="content">

                    <p>Page Content</p>     
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>

</div>    <div id="footer">
            <p>Footer</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<style type="text/css">
*
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
html, body
{
 height: 100%;
 line-height: 1.2;
}

body
{
 background: #000 url(../images/bg-pattern.png) center top repeat;
}

#background
{
 background: url(../images/overlay.png) center top repeat-y;
 min-width: 960px;
 padding-left: 1px;
}

#container
{
 background: red center top no-repeat;
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto -60px;   
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 960px;
 z-index: 10;
}

#header
{
}
#logo
{
 height: 114px;
 width: 960px;
}
#logo a
{
 border: none;
 display: block;
 height: 90px;
 margin: 60px auto;
 width: 640px;
}

#menu
{
 background-color: orange;
}

#border-left
{
 background: blue url(../images/border-left.png) repeat-y 1px -5px;
 height: 100%;
 margin: -4px auto 0;
 width: 912px;
}
#border-right
{
 background: blue url(../images/border-right.png) repeat-y 857px -5px;
 height: 100%;
}
#content
{
 background: yellow url(../images/stripes.gif) center top repeat;
 margin: 35px auto 0;
 min-height: 100px;
 padding: 8px 33px 110px;
 width: 738px;
 z-index: 10;
}

#push {height: 60px;}

#wrapper{
width:960px;
margin:o auto;
}
#footer
{
 background: green url(../images/footergradient.png) repeat-x;

 height: 60px;
 margin: 0 auto;
clear:both;
 text-align: center;
 width: 808px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: hmm.. I don't know if you're seeing something different, but that footer doesn't stick to the bottom for me...

Answer (score 0):

Does this point you in the right direction?

http://jsfiddle.net/zry4T/28/

I've basically placed the footer absolutely at the bottom of the wrapper, and made sure the wrapper is at least as tall as the content.

**EDIT: Updated fiddle**